# Where should I ask programming questions regarding lilypond?

Tags: discussion, scope

I could imagine two places.

https://music.stackexchange.com/

or

https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Therefore the question is, how much TeX-alike is Lilypond. I have the feeling, that I would get better answers on TeX.SX, but I wouldn't blame anybody to close questions for music-typesetting issues as off-topic.

What do you think? Is the TeX-comunity interested in this or should I try to find answers at Music.SX?

Comment: Found another discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168297 They don't seem to be sure, too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the answer is "it depends".

If you search for "Lilypond" on both sites you get a pretty complementary set of questions, and that seems appropriate: the ones here are about the integration of TeX and Lilypond (questions about fonts or engines, for example) while the ones on Music.SX are generally about setting the music itself.

So I think for most questions about setting music, you should probably ask on Music.SX, but for issues related to the integration, here is likely a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I thought. I gave Music.SX a chance and asked something (I am totally new to Lilypond so it's more a "help me"-question). I will see what happens. @Alan, do I mark a discussion answer as an answer? Or should I wait if someone else want's to say something? You got my upvote though.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi On Meta it’s _that_ important. You can wait, of course, for further answers, but in my eyes Alan’s answer seems to meet common sense here.

Answer (score 8):

The best place to ask for help with Lilypond is at lilypond-user@gnu.org.

Lilypond and TeX are similar in that they both produce high-quality printed output from a text-based input file, but they share virtually nothing about the syntax of their input files or the kinds of coding necessary to get the desired output.

You can get a web-based view of the lilypond-user list at http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.lilypond.general